# I don't know how to use "withdrawal symptoms"

Tags: prepositions

I meant which preposition do I use after Withdrawal symptoms? Is it "of" or "from"? And after the preposition should I say, for example, "nicotine" or "nicotine abstinence"?

Comment: Not without the full context. What's your sentence?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the phrase you are trying to say is as follows:

> "*I am suffering **of/from** the withdrawal symptoms of nicotine*"

In this case, you should use **from**.